# Fabric 2.0.1 What is the replacement for env?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, environment-variables, fabric

I have an old fabfile.py (Fabric 1.8.3) which has the following line:

```
env.key_filename = '/etc/appliance/fabric/id_rsa'
```

How do I do the same in Fabric 2.0.1? I tried using fab with -i  option. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `key_filename` as part of `connect_kwargs` when constructing a Connection: [fabric.connection.Connection](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/connection.html#fabric.connection.Connection.__init__)

Alternatively you can set `connect_kwargs`'s `key_filename` key in your [configuration file](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/concepts/configuration.html#basics).